# How do I generate a search snippet similar to core search for a custom search API page?

Tags: 8, search

I installed solr and search_api and search_api_pages. It's all working as expected but, for now, my new search page need a lot of configuration to display correctly. Unlike drupal core search, which automatically just renders a snippet, with search_api one has to configure a view mode specific for search for each content type.
For now, I am looking for a quick and dirty way to generate the exact look and feel of drupal core search.

I looked at drupal core search and it seems the results are processed using `search_excerpt` function. I am not sure how core search generate this snippet but I am interested in doing the same for my custom search api page.

Comment: Why not just configure the view mode for each one?

Comment: So many content types and I wanted something quick.  but I guess I'll have to do it..